# Having one method to save entered text into a string and bring up a uiaction sheet which will then alter the string depending on what button is chosen

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, uitextfield, uiactionsheet

I have a method that should save what is entered into the text field as a string (later to be saved into a NSMutableArray) and then bring up an action sheet after the textfield is exited that will specify the string further depending on which button is clicked.  Please help! I'm in high school attempting to write a program for my senior project so any help is MUCH appreciated! Thanks!

```
@implementation EnteringCoursesViewController

@synthesize classField;
@synthesize indicatedClass;
@synthesize labelClassTitle;
@synthesize selectRotationController;
@synthesize classesEnteredTable;
- (IBAction)classFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender 
            withActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)typeSheet 
            clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] 
                          initWithFormat:@"%@", indicatedClass];
    labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
    labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
    [greeting release];
    [sender resignFirstResponder];

    typeSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Class types"delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Core Class", @"Elective", nil];
    [typeSheet showInView:self.view];
    [typeSheet release];

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
        NSString *indicatedString = indicatedClass;
        NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc]       
                              initWithFormat:@"%@ meets 6 times per rotation",     indicatedString];
        labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
        labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
        [greeting release];
        [indicatedClass release];
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
        NSString *indicatedString = indicatedClass;
        NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] 
                              initWithFormat:@"%@ meets 3 times per rotation", indicatedString];
        labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
        labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
        [greeting release];
        [indicatedClass release];
    } 


}
```

Comments on just the theoretical approach are helpful, but since I'm so new to this I'd love specific coding thanks.

```
@interface EnteringCoursesViewController : UIViewController {
    UILabel             *labelClassTitle;
    NSString            *indicatedClass;
    UITextField         *classField;
    UIViewController    *selectRotationController;
    UITableView         *classesEnteredTable;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel      *labelClassTitle;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString                *indicatedClass;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField  *classField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController      *selectRotationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView  *classesEnteredTable;

- (IBAction)chooseFirstMeeting:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)classFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender withActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)typeSheet 
             clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate the to methods into one by adding multiple arguments to your action that is hooked up with the button. The code should be something like this:

```
- (IBAction)cassFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender 
            withActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)typeSheet 
            clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] 
                          initWithFormat:@"%@", indicatedClass];
    labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
    labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
    [greeting release];

    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    UIActionSheet *typeSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                initWithTitle:@"Class types"delegate:self
                                cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                otherButtonTitles:@"Core Class", @"Elective", nil];
    [typeSheet showInView:self.view];
    [typeSheet release];



    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
        NSString *indicatedString = indicatedClass;
        NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] 
                              initWithFormat:@"%@ meets 6 times per rotation",     indicatedString];
        labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
        labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
        [greeting release];
        [indicatedClass release];
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        self.indicatedClass = classField.text;
        NSString *indicatedString = indicatedClass;
        NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] 
                              initWithFormat:@"%@ meets 3 times per rotation", indicatedString];
        labelClassTitle.text = greeting;
        labelClassTitle.hidden = NO;
        [greeting release];
        [indicatedClass release];
    } 

    [theSmallArray addObject:indicatedClass];

}
```

As I haven't tested the code, there may be errors. Just report back if you got any problems alright?

Comment: You think all in one method is possible? Ok I worked with the code but the only error is that "type sheet redeclared as a different symbol" which I've never gotten before.

Comment: And with this code would the final string displayed as a label be something like "indicatedClass meets however many times per rotation"

Comment: Hey. It's because you are declaring the variable typeSheet. Check your .h file and other places in your class if you have it declared. That is your problem.

Comment: Currently there are no errors, but after I enter into the textfield it simply closes the application. I put the changes in the code above.

Comment: What's your crash log from the console?

Comment: It says this... this means nothing to me but maybe it makes sense to you.

Comment: [Session started at 2012-03-01 19:33:15 +0000.]
2012-03-01 13:33:30.804 SEM2REDO[466:b603] Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x4b1e630>.
2012-03-01 13:33:34.762 SEM2REDO[466:b603] -[EnteringCoursesViewController classFieldDoneEditing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e4fa50
2012-03-01 13:33:34.899 SEM2REDO[466:b603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EnteringCoursesViewController classFieldDoneEditing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e4fa50'

Comment: It's because you have no longer a method called that. The place where you are calling the method for the button you have to specify the new name which is "cassFieldDoneEditing:withActionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:"

Comment: You are getting the error because you call a method that no longer exists

Comment: But I did rename the method as "classFieldDoneEditing", I altered the code above in the question

Comment: As mentioned, the name of that method is not "classFieldDoneEditing:"... It is: classFieldDoneEditing:withActionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:"

Comment: that is what I have... in the code above the method is below and yet it still isn't functioning. 

- (IBAction)classFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender withActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)typeSheet 
    clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

Comment: From your crash log I can only say that the method that is hooked up with the button (maybe in interface builder) is named  "classFieldDoneEditing:". This is wrong. I can't say anything else from your posted crashlog. Sorry.

Comment: well this time it did this.. 2012-03-02 17:15:51.931 SEM2REDO[1648:b603] Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x4b97f30>.
2012-03-02 17:15:58.509 SEM2REDO[1648:b603] -[EnteringCoursesViewController classFieldDoneEditing:withActionSheet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e762d0
2012-03-02 17:15:58.515 SEM2REDO[1648:b603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EnteringCoursesViewController classFieldDoneEditing:withActionSheet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e762d0'

Comment: I'm sorry if this is basic stuff, I'm really trying to get it